# Copy file to publish directory visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, cmd

I'm trying to create a postbuild event where i want o copy a file to the publish directory.

Something like this:

```
    if $(ConfigurationName) == Release xcopy  
    $(ProjectDir)Licences\Test\License.config $(TargetDir) /Y /E
```

But I do not want the file to be published to the TargetDir (which is the binfolder) but to the publish folder. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is the `$(PublishDir)` variable present/set?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release 
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)Licences\Test\License.config" "$(SolutionDir)$(OutDir)" /F /R /Y /I
```

Comment: No that does not do the trick. It just copies the file to the solution level output.